# How to deal with timing issues of JS asynchronous requests？

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

An asynchronous function is frequently called in a short time will cause timing issues. 
My leader tells me that there is a timing issues in my code, how can I modify my code to avoid it.
Here's the code as well:

```
const handleSearch = async (queryName: string) => {
    const result = await getQueryTeacheNameList({ teacher_name: queryName });
    if (result.err_no === 0) {
      const { teacher_list } = result;
      if (Array.isArray(teacher_list)) {
        setOptions(teacher_list as IBackendTeacher[]);
      }
    }
  };
```

The `handleSearch` function will be called frequently.

Suppose we make two requests，the second request is returned first， and the first one is returned. The second result will overwrite the previous one, causing a problem.
So I want to use a simple way to avoid it.

Comment: If you only need the last result of the called method, then you may need a `debounce` function: Check the implementation in lodash: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce  and this explanation https://levelup.gitconnected.com/debounce-in-javascript-improve-your-applications-performance-5b01855e086

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution you can try is using a Debounce function so you can control and prevent multiple requests.
Please check out this post https://medium.com/@TCAS3/debounce-deep-dive-javascript-es6-e6f8d983b7a1 where you can read more about it and maybe come up with a good approach.

This is one simple approach that you can try. :)

Comment: I think Debounce can't avoid  timing issues but can prevent too many calls :)

Comment: Yeah correct, probably it does not prevent that but with this approach, you can limit it at least. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent too many calls to the function and only exec the last one, use debounce function as @Dave Pastor 's answer.

```
const debounce = (fn, time) => {
  let timeout;

  return function() {
    const functionCall = () => fn.apply(this, arguments);

    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(functionCall, time);
  }
}

let TIME_BETWEEN_CALLS = 500 // ms
// some event happen
// then call debounce
target.on("event", debounce(handleSearch, TIME_BETWEEN_CALLS));
```

If you want to handle only first call, you can create a global flag for it and check that flag head first in function:

```
let flag = false;
const handleSearch = async (queryName: string) => {
    if (flag) return;
    flag = true;
    const result = await getQueryTeacheNameList({ teacher_name: queryName });
    if (result.err_no === 0) {
      const { teacher_list } = result;
      if (Array.isArray(teacher_list)) {
        setOptions(teacher_list as IBackendTeacher[]);
      }
    }
    flag = false;
  };
```

And if you want to handle all calls, push calls to a queue and do a loop on that queue.

Answer (score 0):

@thanhdx

I think the request still needs to be sent, but we only deal with the last result.
I hava a solution:

```
  let lastXhr: number,
    flag = 0;
  const handleSearch = async (queryName: string) => {
    const temp = flag++;
    lastXhr = temp;
    let result = await getQueryTeacheNameList({ teacher_name: queryName });
    if (temp < lastXhr) return;
    if (result.err_no === 0) {
      const { teacher_list } = result;
      if (Array.isArray(teacher_list)) {
        setOptions(teacher_list as ec_idl.IBackendTeacher[]);
      }
    }
  };
```